# Implementing numerical integration in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

I have this Python code that implements a rectangular numerical integration. It evaluates the (K-1)-dimensional integral for arbitrary integer \$K \geq 1\$

$$\int_{u_K = 0}^{\gamma}\int_{u_{K-1} = 0}^{\gamma-u_K}\cdots\int_{u_2}^{\gamma-u_K-\cdots-u_3}F_U(\gamma-\sum_{k=2}^Ku_k)f_U(u_2)\cdots f_U(u_K)\,du_2\cdots du_K$$

where \$F_U\$ corresponds to the cdf function in the code, and \$f_U\$ to the pdf. I implemented it using recursion as follows:

```
    #************************** Import necessary libraries******************************************
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
#******************************Set the constant scalars and vectors***************************
start_time = time.time()
KU = 3
eta_dB = 3
eta = 10**(eta_dB/10)
ExpanF = 50

tdB = np.arange(-5,11,4)
tVec = 10**(tdB/10)
thVec = (tVec/eta)*(ExpanF-eta*(KU-1))

N = 10000 # For simulation

du = 0.01

#******************************Define functions to be used***************************************
#Define the CDF of U
def CDF(u):
      return 1-1/(u+1)

#Define the PDF of U
def pdf(u):
     return 1/((1+u))**2

def FK(h, k):
    #print(f'h is {h}, and k is {k}')
    if k == 1:
        res = CDF(h)
    else:
        #n_iter = int(h/du)
        res =  0
        u = 0
        while u < h:
            res += FK(h-u, k-1)*pdf(u)*du
            u += du
    return res

#*******************Find the numerical and simulation values of the integral******************
ResultNum = []
ResultSim = []

if (ExpanF-eta*(KU-1)) > 0:
    for t in thVec:
    # Numerical
        ResultNum.append(1-FK(t, KU))
    # Simulation
        count = 0
        for n in range(0, N):
            if np.sum(np.random.exponential(1, (1, KU))/np.random.exponential(1, (1, KU))) <= t:
                count += 1
        ResultSim.append(1-count/N)
```

The parameter `du` is the resolution of the numerical integral, and the smaller, the more accurate the numerical approximation is. However, decreasing `du` comes at the expense of more computational time using the above code. For example I tried to run the above code on my machine Intel i5 @2.5 GH with 6 GB of RAM for `du=0.0001`, and it took 15 hours and didn't finish, at which case I had to abort it.

Is there anyway the above code can be optimized to run significantly faster? I tried C++, and I got a 30x speed factor using the same code and algorithm, but I was wondering if I can get a similar or better speed up factor in Python.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.

Comment: Did you try [`scipy.integrate.nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad)?

Comment: @GarethRees Not really. Can it be used for an arbitrary number of nested integrals?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad): "Function signature should be `func(x0, x1, ..., xn, t0, t1, ..., tm)`. Integration is carried out in order. That is, integration over `x0` is the innermost integral, and `xn` is the outermost."

Comment: @GarethRees Doesn't sound like what I am looking for. I don't want to specify the functions and limits each time I change K. I need a dynamic program where all I change is K. That is why I am trying to program the numerical integration from scratch. Otherwise, I would have used the built-in numerical integrations in MATLAB or any other platform. But these functions are not flexible for an arbitrary number of nested integrals.

Comment: It should be easy to write code to bridge the interface gap.

Comment: @GarethRees Could you please give me some hint? I am still not sure how to use it. Suppose I want to evaluate the following for some positive value \$\gamma\$ $$\int_{u_3=0}^{\gamma}\int_{u_2=0}^{\gamma-u_3}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\gamma-u_3-u_2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+u_2}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{1+u_3}\right)^2\,du_2du_3$$. How can I do it with scipy.integrate.nquad?

Comment: That might be a good question for Stack Overflow, but not for Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

> I have this Python code that implements a rectangular numerical integration.

In what sense "rectangular"? Or is that as opposed to contour integration?

> It evaluates the (K-1)-dimensional integral for arbitrary integer \$K \geq 1\$
>
> $$\int_{u_K = 0}^{\gamma}\int_{u_{K-1} = 0}^{\gamma-u_K}\cdots\int_{u_2}^{\gamma-u_K-\cdots-u_3}F_U(\gamma-\sum_{k=2}^Ku_k)f_U(u_2)\cdots f_U(u_K)\,du_2\cdots du_K$$
>
> where \$F_U\$ corresponds to the cdf function in the code, and \$f_U\$
>   to the pdf.

It would probably help to rewrite it in fully symmetric form: $$\underset{\substack{u_i \ge 0 \\ u_1 + \cdots + u_K \le \gamma}}{\int \cdots \int} f_U(u_1)\cdots f_U(u_K) \textrm{d}u_1 \cdots \textrm{d}u_K$$

Then you can exploit the symmetry to divide the polytope of interest into equivalent chunks and only integrate each chunk once.

---

> I implemented it using recursion as follows:
>
> ```
>     #************************** Import necessary libraries******************************************
> import numpy as np
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import time
> #******************************Set the constant scalars and vectors***************************
> start_time = time.time()
> ```

So far I understand.

> ```
> KU = 3
> eta_dB = 3
> eta = 10**(eta_dB/10)
> ExpanF = 50
>
> tdB = np.arange(-5,11,4)
> tVec = 10**(tdB/10)
> thVec = (tVec/eta)*(ExpanF-eta*(KU-1))
> ```

What do any of those mean? "*constant scalars and vectors*" is not an adequate description.

> ```
> N = 10000 # For simulation
>
> du = 0.01
>
> #******************************Define functions to be used***************************************
> #Define the CDF of U
> def CDF(u):
>       return 1-1/(u+1)
>
> #Define the PDF of U
> def pdf(u):
>      return 1/((1+u))**2
> ```

If \$f_U\$ is that simple, it might make more sense to tackle it with symbolic integration rather than quadrature.

> ```
> def FK(h, k):
>     #print(f'h is {h}, and k is {k}')
>     if k == 1:
>         res = CDF(h)
>     else:
>         #n_iter = int(h/du)
>         res =  0
>         u = 0
>         while u < h:
>             res += FK(h-u, k-1)*pdf(u)*du
>             u += du
>     return res
> ```

This could use some comments. It seems to be first order quadrature. If you use a higher order, maybe a larger step size will give you equally accurate results much faster.

> ```
> #*******************Find the numerical and simulation values of the integral******************
> ResultNum = []
> ResultSim = []
>
> if (ExpanF-eta*(KU-1)) > 0:
>     for t in thVec:
>     # Numerical
>         ResultNum.append(1-FK(t, KU))
>     # Simulation
>         count = 0
>         for n in range(0, N):
>             if np.sum(np.random.exponential(1, (1, KU))/np.random.exponential(1, (1, KU))) <= t:
>                 count += 1
>         ResultSim.append(1-count/N)
> ```

I'm missing a lot of context here.